# ConTeXt is loading fonts, dependent on the cwd

Tags: fonts, context-mkiv, linux, ligatures, ebgaramond

I have a ConTeXt source file: `~/foo/mwe.tex`

```
\definefontfamily [mwe] [serif] [EBGaramond]
\setupbodyfont [mwe,14pt]

\starttext
`If you optimize everything, you will always be unhappy.' -- Donald Knuth.
\stoptext
```

If I'm in `~/foo`, and build the file with `context mwe.tex`, I get a completely blank page – I assume that ConTeXt hasn't managed to load the font...

...however, **if I'm in my home directory** (`~`), and build the file 'remotely' using 
 `context foo/mwe.tex`, **the page outputs** (though with some quirks – the ffi ligature doesn't form if the ffi is not followed immediately by a space :/).

(Here's an image of the non-working ligatures)
[image: broken ligatures]

**What is causing the strange behaviour, and how can I fix it?**

---

**EDIT:** As per Herbert's request, I created a new subdir from `~` (`bar`), copied the file across (`mwe.tex`), and built it (in `bar`). No change: the page is still blank. However, I did notice this in ConTeXt's output (the complete log is [here](http://hastebin.com/zugimubuki.hs)):

```
fonts           > !! No bodyfont has been defined and no defaults have been
fonts           > !! loaded (maybe due to a missing \starttext)
```

This warning didn't appear when the file was built 'remotely' from `~` – the log for this one is [here](http://hastebin.com/piqekusaja.hs).

**EDIT 2:** In desperation, I followed Aditya's advice and re-installed ConTeXt through `yaourt context-minimals-git`. Using the 2016 version seems to fix the problem completely, ligatures *and* directory-selective building – thanks, Aditya!

(However, if anyone manages to replicate and solve the behaviour in TL2015, I will happily accept their answer.)

Comment: crate a new subdirectory and create the test file in this subdir. Then run `context <file>`. Does it work? I have no problem with an up-to-date TL 2016 and mkiv

Comment: MkIV in TL2016 ships with a fully-featured typescript for EB Garamond, which even se.ects correct optical sizes.  You can use it via `\setupbodyfont[ebgaramond]`.

Comment: @Henri; I have a feeling that I haven't yet updated to TL2016... is this question still relevant if that's where the problem lies?

Comment: @digitalis_ In my up-to-date frozen TL2015 there is also an EB Garamond typescript.  I didn't test it though.  But updating to TL2016 is nevertheless a good idea.

Comment: @Henri; is there one in TL2015? I had to get EB Garamond through `yaourt`. I installed TL2015 through `pacman -S texlive-most`, so that might be the problem...

Comment: @digitalis_, If you are arch linux, you can also install [context minimals](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/context-minimals-git/) through AUR, which installs context at `/opt/context-minimals` This installation can work in parallel with TL, and is easier to keep up to date.

Comment: @Herbert; I have carried out your request: see the edit in the question.

Comment: Can you post the complete log (as it appears on the terminal) rather than a snippet.

Comment: @Aditya; I have placed links to a pastebin, with the logs in full, in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has been solved by upgrading ConTeXt.